# passing a list to javascript in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, list

I have a list of image urls that I am trying to display.  I am passing the list from the controller to the view.  I know that the list is being created successfully.  But when it gets to the view, javascript interprets it as "`*System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]*`" not as the actual list.  This causes the images not to be displayed.

Here is the line of code that I am using to assign the list to js variable:

`var imageUrls = '@Model.PicUrls';`

and the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pics = _ctx.Image.Select(m => m).Take(10).ToList<ImageModel>();

        var picUrls = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= pics.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            picUrls.Add(pics[i].ImageUrl);

        }

        var outModel = new ViewPostViewModel
        {
            PicUrls = picUrls
        };

        return View(outModel);
```

I tried to return a Json object but then the page literally only displayed was the completed list.

```
return Json(outModel.PicUrls, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So, the Json advice worked somewhat but it is not quite there

Answer (score 0):

Getting

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

because you're model value PicUrls default ToString() implementation is to return its type.

You could store PicUrls as a JSON string, then parse to javascript array in your js.

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pics = _ctx.Image.Select(m => m).Take(10).ToList();

```
    var picUrls = String.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i <= pics.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        picUrls += (picUrls != String.Empty ? ", " : "") + @"""" + pics[i].ImageUrl + @"""";
    }

    var outModel = new ViewPostViewModel
    {
        PicUrls = @"[" + picUrls + "]";
    };

    return View(outModel);
```

In your js, use

```
var imageUrls = JSON.parse('@Model.PicUrls');
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pics = _ctx.Image.Select(m => m.ImageUrl)
        .Take(10).ToList();

        var picUrls = new List();

        for (int i = 0; i <= pics.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            picUrls.Add(pics[i]);

        }

        var outModel = new ViewPostViewModel
        {
            PicUrls = picUrls
        };
return Json(outModel.PicUrls, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried the code and I got a blank page with the list of urls displayed.  Same problem I ran into before.